# How to create a correlation matrix using rounding to two decimal places in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm hoping to round to two decimal places in a correlation matrix. The code I use for the matrix is this:

```
corr RELATIONSHIP TotalOwnerCommission anxiety enjoyment BEH_SIM sptconf NEG_EFFICACY spteffort SPTEFFORT_OTHER SIM_VALUES COOP_MOTIV COMP_MOTIV
```

How can I round the decimal places in the matrix so that they trail on?

Comment: Already answered in a thread you posted in at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1515817-correlation-output-with-two-decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ssc install cpcorr 

. cpcorr mpg weight price, format(%3.2f)
(obs=74)

           mpg  weight   price
   mpg    1.00
weight   -0.81    1.00
 price   -0.47    0.54    1.00
```

.